# Почему переменная i равна true если должно быть confirm("Родители разрешили?")

Tags: javascript

```js
function checkAge(age) {
  return (age > 18) ? true : confirm("Родители разрешили?");
}



let i = checkAge(15);
```

Comment: запустите свой код, работает как надо

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае в переменной i будет результат выбора конфирма

Comment: @Arthur, потому, что confirm является функцией JS и возвращает логический результат true или false, в таком случае, сначала вызывается confirm, потом ответ от функции checkAge и уже после присвоение переменной i